# Creating an Ajax Module for Magento

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

I have tried to follow this tutorial;

http://www.atwix.com/magento/ajax-requests-in-magento/

But have become slightly confused towards the end.

The module I am trying to create is one that will use AJAX to load in the dynamic values needed for the Advanced Google Remarketing script. The code to generate these values works fine, as I have tested this in our test environment without caching. Once caching is introduced the values stop being correct - so would like it to load in with Ajax each time.

These are my files;

**\app\code\local\CompanyName\Remarketing\controllers\AjaxController.php**

```html
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     default_modern
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2011 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */

public function remarketingAction()
{
    echo '<!-- Google Code for Remarketing Tag -->';
    echo '<!--';
    echo 'Remarketing tags may not be associated with personally identifiable information or placed on pages related to sensitive categories. See more information and instructions on how to setup the tag on: http://google.com/ads/remarketingsetup';
    echo '-->';

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'var google_tag_params = {';
        if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'homepage'  && Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms') {
            echo 'ecomm_pagetype: \'home\'';
        } else if ($this->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'result' || $this->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'advanced') {
            echo 'ecomm_pagetype: \'searchresults\'';
        } else if ($this->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'catalog' || $this->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'category') {
            echo 'ecomm_pagetype: \'category\'';
        } else if ($this->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'product' || $this->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'current_product')  {
            $product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
            $prices = Mage::registry('current_product')->getFinalPrice();
            $prices = number_format($prices, 2, '.', '');
            echo ('ecomm_prodid: '.$product_id.',');
            echo 'ecomm_pagetype: \'product\',';
            echo ('ecomm_totalvalue: '.$prices);
        } else if ($this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'success') {
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());
            $prices = $quote['grand_total'];
            $prices = number_format($prices, 2, '.', '');
            echo 'ecomm_pagetype: \'purchase\',';
            echo ('ecomm_totalvalue: '.$prices);
        } else if ($this->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'checkout' || $this->getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'onepagecheckout' || $this->getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'checkout') {
            $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
            $prices = $quote['grand_total'];
            $prices = number_format($prices, 2, '.', '');
            echo 'ecomm_pagetype: \'cart\',';
            echo ('ecomm_totalvalue: '.$prices);
        } else {
            echo 'ecomm_pagetype: \'other\'';
        }
    echo '};';
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo '/* <![CDATA[ */ ';
    echo 'var google_conversion_id = xxxxxxxxxx;';
    echo 'var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;';
    echo 'var google_remarketing_only = true;';
    echo ' /* ]]> */ ';
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">';
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<noscript>';
    echo '<div style="display:inline;">';
    echo '<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1055454704/?value=0&guid=ON&script=0"/>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</noscript>';
}
```

**\app\code\local\CompanyName\Remarketing\etc\config.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<config>
    <modules>
        <CompanyName_Remarketing>
           <version>0.0.1</version>
        </CompanyName_Remarketing>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <remarketing>
                    <file>remarketing.xml</file>
                </remarketing>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**\app\design\frontend\Package\Theme\Layout\remarketing.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento Enterprise Edition
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Magento Enterprise Edition License
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_EE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://www.magentocommerce.com/license/enterprise-edition
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     enterprise_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://www.magentocommerce.com/license/enterprise-edition
 */

-->
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <remarketing_ajax_remarketing>
        <block type="remarketing/remarketing" name="root" template="page/html/footer.phtml" />
    </remarketing_ajax_remarketing>
</layout>
```

**\app\design\frontend\Package\Theme\template\page\html\footer.phtml**

```html
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     default_modern
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2011 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<div class="footer-container">
    <div class="footer">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_block') ?>
    </div>
    <address><?php echo $this->getCopyright() ?></address>

    <div id="remarketing">
    </div>

    <script>
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/remarketing/ajax/remarketing",
            type: "POST",
            data: "size="+jQuery(this).val(),
            success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#remarketing').html(data);
            }
        });
    </script>

</div>
```

Hopefully it is something simple I have performed wrong.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: what is the version of magento you are working?

Comment: Sorry Enterprise v1.12.0.2

Comment: Can you explain the part "the values stop being correct".I am not sure about this but i have experienced a similar issue in magento CE 1.4 .When caching was enabled the function used to check whether the user is in home page didn't worked as expected and i had to find an alternate solution to detect home page.

Comment: Sorry - I should mention we are using the Varnish Cache.

Comment: For instance if someone views the cart page with a £12 product in the cart, the tag will say ecomm_totalvalue: 12.00. If the customer then changed it to contain two of these products, the tag would still read as 12.00 as that would be cached.